# Policy to allow lambda:InvokeFunction to an IAM Assumed Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am using trying to invoke a Lambda from another Lambda, I am getting the error:

> AccessDeniedException: User: [role ARN] is not authorized to perform:
>   lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: [Lambda ARN]

After researching, I found put that I need to attach a Policy  to the IAM user to allow the action.

I'm wondering if there's any AWS Managed Policy which allows `lambda:InvokeFunction`?
If not, what would be the best minimalist policy JSON to create?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A managed role would be the `AWSLambdaRole`.

If you want to create it on your own:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "<ARN of the function which is allowed to be invoked>"
    }
  ]
}
```

For the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) you could also put `*` (then all functions are allowed to be invoked). Also, you could provide a list of multiple function ARNs.